# How do i figure how long file_get_contents took to load a web page?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using `file_get_contents` to load a webpage's content, how would i check how long it took to get the page?!

Comment: Well, take a look at php's `time()` function. Take two timestamps, one before and one after the loading, then build the difference...

Comment: @arkascha Good suggestion, Thanks!

Comment: If you used curl it would tell you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for asking this, it's very simple and easy to do, all that's needed to be done is declaring a variable with the returned number of seconds from the time() function as it's value, and then compare it later

```
<?php 
$before = time();
//ProcessHere
$now = time()-$before;
?>
```